# how do I make this delete button work, im new to laravel so i really don't know

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

This is my jquery code

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteStudent', function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
        console.log("it Works");
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "/delete-student/" + id,
            dataType: "json",

            data: {
                "id": id,
                "_token": token,
            },
            success: function (){
                console.log("it Works");
            }
            });
        });
```

Here is my controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Student::find($id)->delete($id);
        return response()->json([
            'success'=> 'Record deleted successfully'
        ]); 
}
```

//here is my web.php routing
Route::delete('delete-student/{id}', [StudentController::class, 'destroy']);

Comment: What about it isn't working? Do you get a specific error or unexpected behaviour? What debugging have you done? Please give us a clue about the actual problem.

Comment: P.S. Have you actually set up the webserver to respond to DELETE requests and forward them to the right controller action? Since you're using a URL called delete_student anyway, it's probably not necessary, you could just use a POST

Comment: The console says "DELETE 404(not found)

Comment: Well then either the URL isn't configured properly to go to the controller action, and/or the DELETE method isn't set up properly. I'm not a Laravel expert, but you need to check your Route config

Comment: Can you please elaborate the POST method, or do you have any links where i can follow the steps?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not a laravel expert so I can't tell you the specifics unfortunately, but there should be plenty of tutorials and documentation you can find by searching, which explain the concepts of configuring your routing, and making sure your URLs match up with your controller actions.

Comment: Aight, thanks for your contribution good sir. Have a great day!

Comment: No worries. Possibly someone else will take a look at this and have more insight.

Comment: do you have the adequate routing in your ```routes/web.php``` file?

Comment: Update your question with the contents of ```routes/web.php``` file

Comment: yes i have a routing in my web.php file

Comment: Route::delete('delete-student/{id}', [StudentController::class, 'destroy']);

Comment: Can you check if DELETE is enabled? It might be blocked by hosting policies.

Comment: Okay. I am coming up with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes/web.php` file. Change what you have from

```
Route::delete('delete-student/{id}', [StudentController::class, 'destroy']);
```

TO THIS

```
Route::post('delete-student/{id}', [StudentController::class, 'destroy'])->name('student.delete');
```

Change your jQuery code to this:

```
   $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteStudent', function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var url = "{{ route('student.delete', ':id') }}";
        url = url.replace(':id', id);
        var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
        console.log("it Works");
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",

            data: {'_method':'POST', '_token': token},
            success: function (){
                console.log("it Works");
            }
            });
        });
```

This is a better approach and will definitely work.

**EXPLANATION** : You first assign a name to the route so you can assign the `id` parameter to the `route()` helper function.

Next, use a `POST` route instead of `DELETE`, since you are submitting a form via AJAX.

Next, assign the url to a variable in your JavaScript, then pass it to your AJAX request.

That's all!

Comment: Did you update your ```routes/web.php``` file?

Comment: yes i copy pasted all your answer, still getting a 404 :((

Comment: I need to see your code.  check my profile.